# Big Query Concat String in FROM Clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation

I have multiple tables like as follows in BigQuery:

> PROJECT_NAME.DATA_SET_NAME.TABLENAME0
>
> PROJECT_NAME.DATA_SET_NAME.TABLENAME1
>
> PROJECT_NAME.DATA_SET_NAME.TABLENAME2
>
> PROJECT_NAME.DATA_SET_NAME.TABLENAME3
>
> PROJECT_NAME.DATA_SET_NAME.TABLENAME4
>
> ...

I want to empty some of these tables via a loop but don't know how to call the **CONCAT** in **FROM** clause:

```
DECLARE count INT64 DEFAULT 0;
WHILE count < 1000 Do
  DELETE FROM CONCAT('PROJECT_NAME.DATA_SET_NAME.TABLENAME' , count ) WHERE TRUE;
  SET count = count + 1;
END WHILE
```

But it's not working, it says I cannot use CONCAT in FROM part.
Anyone knows how should I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in BigQuery, unless you script it outside BigQuery.

There's an open feature request, that you should subscribe to - to indicate interest and follow any new developments:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142531516